# Removing "Chapter 1" just before my bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

The relevant latex is below. When I compile, I get a large Chapter 1 in bold above my bibliography. How can I remove this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\def\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Introduction.}
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\end{thebibliography}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the default would be an unnumbered chapter but you have used

```
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
```

where `numbib` specifies that the bibliography should be numbered